# How to increase JWT Token Expire time in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

I uses tymon/jwt auth package for integrate jwt api authentication in my laravel project. Now i realize my token is destroyed after a particular time. So i need to increase the expires time of the token . I trying to do it like below-

```
JWTAuth::attempt($input,['exp' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(150)->timestamp]))
```

But This way its not working . Can anyone help me?

Comment: Ah yes, the `tymon/jwt` package that everyone is using, assuming it provides a stateless authentication (which it does not). It just stores a user-id and retrieves the model with a DB request every time. Just wanted to throw that out here.

Comment: Do you want it to never expire?

Comment: Yes,,, i want the token never expire.

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization Server is the one that is responsible for setting expiration time of your tokens. If you're in control of the Authorization Server, then you should change some settings there.

Usually you will receive a refresh token when authorizing with an Authorization Server (the token response may contain an access token and refresh token). If you received a refresh token then you can use it to get a new access token from the Authorization Server, once your token expires.

Answer (score 0):

You could change it in file

**config/jwt.php**

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 1440)
```

or change in .env file